# Rails - WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, csrf

I'm using some javascript called jpegcam (with paperclip, following [these directions](http://lassebunk.dk/2011/02/19/paperclip-jpegcam-webcam-rails3/)) and on different occasions it's creating faulty CSRF tokens. This is the only place in application with this issue. The bad tokens have '+' characters in the middle.

**This section in the JS is the problem** `webcam.set_api_url('<%= upload_users_path %>' + '?' + csrf_param + "=" + encodeURI(encodeURI(csrf_token)));`

Warning messages:

```
Started POST "/users/upload?authenticity_token=N0x/rDOgyC6AutbXzx8sZXLwDnB9zQ+NwWefXTpiSfE=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013- 06-04 01:06:34 -0400
...
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"N0x/rDOgyC6AutbXzx8sZXLwDnB9zQ NwWefXTpiSfE="}
 WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
...
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms
```

JS (in page view) looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onload_complete(msg) {
    // fetch the CSRF meta tag data
    var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
    var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

    // reset the api URL appending the auth token parameter
    webcam.set_api_url('<%= upload_users_path %>' + '?' + csrf_param + "=" + encodeURI(encodeURI(csrf_token)));
}
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the csrf-token on the header of your request as X-CSRF-Token. 
`request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", csrf_token)`
That did the trick the last time I had problems with CSRF

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your /application.js

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript") 
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It looks like the issue with the line `webcam.set_api_url('<%= upload_users_path %>' + '?' + csrf_param + "=" + encodeURI(encodeURI(csrf_token)));` just putting bad tokens with plus-signs mixed in somehow.